# Remove First 8 columns from ls Output with AWK

Tags: awk

I would like to use AWK to remove the first 8 columns from the following output:

```
ls -l

lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user   23 jul 27 00:04 file1.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  107 may  8 13:59 file 2 with spaces.mp3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user   11 jul 24 19:43 file3-with-hyphens.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user   11 jul 24 19:43 and_another_file4_with_underscores.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  107 may  8 13:59 file 5 with way more spaces than the rest.mp3
```

and send the result to a text file. I can do that manually in vim with visual block select,
however I would prefer to have a script to do it automatically.

Looking around I was able to find 
[this](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/11/awk-examples-insert-remove-update-fields.html) page where, by changing the relevant parts of the 9th example and piping the output to itself as many times as required, I was able to get the desired result, but I feel that there must be a better (more elegant and/or compact) way to do it but haven't been able to find it or come up with my own.

My final code is the following:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i!=x)f=f?f FS $i:$i;print f;f=""}' x=1 ~/file_folder_content.txt | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i!=x)f=f?f FS $i:$i;print f;f=""}' x=1 | ... | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i!=x)f=f?f FS $i:$i;print f;f=""}' x=1 >> ~/file_folder_content.txt
```

Note 1: I expect the actual output from the `ls` command to be much larger than this.

Note 2: I tried to print the 9th field, but since some file names contain spaces, this only prints the first word in the file name.

Comment: Remove the first 8 columns? That output only has 8 columns. Are you trying to just print the filenames? `ls -1` does that.

Comment: Trial and error left me with this ridiculous command: `ls -l | tail -n +2 | column -tdN test -o "|" | cut -d "|" -f 9` - It prints only the 9th column. There must be a better way but hey, it works, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want in `awk`:

```
ls -l | awk '$9~/./{for (i=1;i<9;i++){$i=""}; gsub(/^ +/,""); print}'
```

Here's a slightly different approach in `perl`:

```
ls -l | perl -lane 'if ($F[7]=~/./) {s/.*$F[7]//; print}'
```

**Note:** I cannot but recommend you think thoroghly about what you actually want to achieve, since there might be better ways. As mentioned by [@confetti](https://superuser.com/users/926024/confetti), just printing the filenames is more straighforwardly accomplished with `ls -1`.

**Note:** As correctly pointed out in the comments, this solution is not robust. I would add that no parsing of `ls` can be considered safe and sound.

**Learning AWK:** Since the OP explained in the comments that this question is part of a broader quest to become proficient in AWK, I have a few recommendations.

- Go through this fine AWK [tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)
- Keep this [reference guide](http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_toc.html) always open
- Read this short [article](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr) on AWK's built-in variables
- Study some of the countless answers to AWK [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/awk) on StackExchange
- Consider the alternatives, [summarised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/366980/7659430) here

Comment: Create a file with multiple consecutive spaces in its name and see what your command prints for it.

Comment: (for the awk) or a file named `0000` or `-00.00` or `0e42`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 rightful observation! This significant case can be taken into account substituting `$9` with `$9~/./` and `$F[7]` with `$F[7]=~/./`, but the whole idea of parsing `ls` output should be reexamined.

Comment: @simlev The broader problem that I'm trying to solve is to become proficient with AWK, so this was just a problem that I came up with to practice, but couldn't find a way to solve (except for the code that I provided). I was expecting this to be a fairly inefficient way of doing things, but was also expecting to learn a better way to do it in the process.

Comment: @simlev I `diff`ed the output from your answer with my manually edited file and they are equal, so this is the answer I was looking for. Plus, It gives a better way to do it and mentions the shortcomings of parsing the result from `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). `ls -1` should print what you want. This option is required by POSIX so it's unlikely your `ls` doesn't support it.

However if you're about to parse the result, you [shouldn't use `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) at all. Use `find`, preferably with `-print0` action.

So `ls` is not the right tool. If you insist on parsing the bare `ls` output anyway, then `awk` may not be the right tool either. Reasoning:

- Your columns are separated by spaces; sometimes there are two or three consecutive spaces, this differs from line to line. So with this naive separator a filename in one line may begin at Nth column, while in another line it's at (N+1)th column.
- You can tell `awk` to treat multiple spaces as one separator (`awk -F ' +'`) but this will mangle filenames with many consecutive spaces.
- So you need some logic to identify where a filename starts in every single line. This can be done (I believe `awk` is Turing complete), I can't give you any working solution though.

Even the output of `ls -1` shouldn't be parsed, `ls -l` is worse.

Comment: Once you point out `ls` is not robust, it's no longer useful to speculate about how it could be parsed with any particular tool. To further prove how utterly useless this is, I for one have group names that contain spaces.